# I've loved outer space and the idea of moving to a new planet since forever, but

Tags: earth

Why is it so important that we explore outer space so much even though our own Earth is riddled with so many problems such as poverty, climate change and threats to biodiversity? Why is it important that we invest our financial resources into space science when there are clearly more immediate things we need to focus on? And, why is it important that we try to find another planet that is capable of supporting human life? Why can't we invest that money into making our own Earth a better place to live than it is now?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi And welcome to space Stack Exchange! If you have a look around at other questions you will notice the aim is to have questions that can have factual and referenced answers and at the moment your question is more philosophical and opinion. What I would suggest is editing your question to ask explicitly 'how much has the search for earth like planets cost' rather than 'why are humans like this?'.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We do not explore one at the expense of the other. The US spent ~25 Billion dollars on space related ventures in 2022. This accounts for less than 1 percent of the federal budget. Considering the technological advances this money brings, it would be undeniably worse for humanity to spend that money elsewhere.

Comment: Additionally if your thought is "don't explore outer space until all the problems on earth are fixed" then outer space would never be explored.

Comment: Is not what you asked but suggest having a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_travel and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation the search for earthlike planets is less about 'lets go pillage a fresh planet' and more 'are we alone'.

Comment: Take a look at this document from NASA https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/Benefits-Stemming-from-Space-Exploration-2013-TAGGED.pdf  and wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefits_of_space_exploration The technology we have to develop to explore outer space is technology that can later benefit humanity to make our world a better place. Take solar panels as an example. We needed to develop them and make them efficient in order to produce electricity for satellites and spacecraft. Exploring Mars requires devices that are robust and very energy efficient.. and a large *et cetera*

Answer (score 2):

The problems of humanity are largely political problems of our own making and not financial. Most could be solved if "we" had the political will to do so. But humanity is not a unified "we" and does not have a collective will. Humanity is a range of separate nations, companies, individuals and organisations many of which pull in different directions for diverse reasons.

"we" would be better off if there were no wars and the rich gave to the poor etc but unfortunately that is not the way human nature works and stopping all space exploration would have no impact at all.

In fact why pick out space exploration as opposed to defence spending (the US spends ~20 billion dollars on space and about 750 billion dollars on defence every year). What about cosmetics wouldn't it be better if people stopped spending money on cosmetics and gave the money to the poor?

At least Space exploration can be exciting and inspirational. It has also provided us with telecommunications, GPS navigation, discoveries in physics, astronomy and much else besides.

The discovery of life on Mars could be a scientific bonanza in biology and even medicine as well as philosophy. How similar would that life be to life on Earth?

It would also be very useful at the moment to learn how to better manage our planet and recycle things. What better way than to isolate a few dozen people on a remote outpost where their lives depend on the maintenance of their local biosphere and recycling everything.

But we don't know what we don't know and the biggest benefits are likely to come from surprises. People rarely set out to make discoveries they usually happen when we are looking for something else.

Take for example that fool Columbus. Everyone knew that he had got his sums wrong and there was no shortcut to China across the Atlantic Ocean. Columbus and all his men and ships were destined to end up at the bottom of a vast Ocean they couldn't possibly hope to cross. It would have been much better to give the money to the poor instead.